# R - Better way to view data frame outputs on console

Tags: r, dataframe, output

I'm looking for a better way to view output of the data frame in the console.
The computer that I'm using has high security restrictions, so installing many of the more popular packages such as `tidyr` and `tibble` is not possible.

What I want is for the ouput to be more compact and not wrap in the console.

Is there a way to use base R to improve the console output for data frames?

Comment: Look into the options of `str`, including `max.level` and `vec.len`. Since you're in a position of not using `tidyr`, then why do you suspect you can use other non-standard packages? Regardless, this question is ripe for closing: not only does it not show something reproducible with expected/desired output, it is a bit close to an [off-topic reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); specifically, questions asking us to *"suggest a software library ... are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers"*.

Comment: Maybe help("head").

Comment: You can't even install a package into your own home directory?

Comment: I can downloan and intall the packages when I move the package folder off the sever, but I get an error whenever I load most of them 
`.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcpp', details:
  call: new_dummyObject(.dummyInstancePointer)
  error: object 'class__dummyInstance' not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `edit` your data.frame without changing it. It will open a new window for you to see. There is an `editor` parameter which allows to choose an editor of your choise.

Or you could page through the data:

`page(mtcars, method = "print")`

Comment: both of those options are very good. I also use the `View()` function. although both `edit()` and `page()` allows me to open the results in another window.

Comment: for `page()` how do you set a default application to open the results it? 
It keeps opening up in 'Window can't open this file' box. I select the checkbox 'Always use the selection...' but it still comes up the next time i run it?